# iPhone 12 pro vs iPad pro 6th gen battery life

Tags: iphone, ipad, battery

I've been playing call of duty mobile on my iPhone 12 Pro (battery health at about 92%). 100% battery gives about 6-7 hours of game play.

I also tried with a brand new iPad Pro 6th generation, and it only lasts 4-5 hours.

I used the same (the lowest) graphic settings as my iPhone 12 Pro. The only difference is the iPad is running in 120 frames per second while the iPhone is at 60, but even with that, shouldn't the iPad battery last far longer than the iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

The battery on the phone is 2815 mAh, compared to 10566 mAh on the iPad, so all things being equal, you'd expect 3.75 greater life.

But all things are not equal. The screen is nearly twice the size; 2732 x 2048 compared to 2532 x 1170 on the phone. The fps may also have an effect, as you suggest.

The M2 has 12 cores and is likely to consume more power than the 6-core A14. It's possible that powering more RAM and more storage may also take a toll.

There may also differences between iOS and iPadOS in terms of multi-tasking, e.g. what the device is doing in the background while it's running your game.

Apple estimates the phone will provide 17 hours of video playback; the iPad is rated for 10 hours.

Comment: Compare https://support.apple.com/kb/SP832?viewlocale=en_AM&locale=en_AM to https://support.apple.com/kb/SP883?viewlocale=en_AM&locale=en_AM